# Pagination within an iframe

Tags: html, codeigniter, iframe

I currently have an iframe which displays the results of my query in database in a table. I tried using codeigniter pagination class and I can see the page links in iframe; however I can't seem to make the links work since my url is not exactly changing

i.e.

```
http://localhost/DTS/index.php/home
```

So I would like to ask if it is possible to actually paginate using codeigniter in my situation or should I start looking into other ways i.e. javascript or ajax

Comment: sorry if I'm explaining it incorrectly. It's my first time actually using the pagination class and it seemed like what I needed when I was looking into codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind the pagination class...I just made next and back button which requests the next set of output from the database